# Assembly: Accessing command line arguments in 64-bit CLI

Tags: assembly, command, arguments, line

I tried googling it but to no avail. I want to get such information like number of arguments and the strings from DOS command line of Windows 8.1 accessed via assembly programs. I mean I want to do it primitively without using any Windows library. Is it even possible? Thanks

Comment: You have to use the GetCommandLineA or GetCommandLineW Windows APIs.

Comment: Ross Ridge is there any other more primitive way to do it like in Linux?

Comment: Not that I know of. You can't do anything on Windows without using the APIs. If it helps any, GetCommandLine returns the command line as single string. You can "primitively" count and split up the arguments yourself if you want.

Comment: If he compiled his asm to an old school .com program he could access them manually no?  Like in [this example](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/55847-cmd-line-arguments-in-dos/)..